# Microsoft Oauth2 (token endpoint) - invalid client error

Tags: javascript, web, oauth, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get offline access to the outlook calendar from a webview.
(using the authorization_code oauth flow)
currently im doing the following

the javascript website calls the
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
endpoint. Then I set the redirect URI to my spring endpoint.

The spring service is getting a valid code/state, so I assume I did everything correct until now.

Then I am calling the /token endpoint with the following parameters

```
{
    grant_type: authorization_code,
    client_id: <client_id>,
    client_secret: client_secret,
    redirect_uri: <THE SAME AS USED BY AUTHENTICATE>,
    scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read
}
```

I am getting the following error back:

```
{
    "error" : "invalid_client",
    "error_description" : "The OAuth client was not found."
}
```

I made sure twice that the client secret/id is set correct. I used the microsoft registration portal to create my application, and Web as platform. Live SDK support is also enabled.

https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

Does anyone have suggestions why this doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass back the authorization code you received from the first call in the body of your second call. The following are the parameters you need to pass back:

- grant_type - Should be authorization_code
- code - The auth code you received
- client_id - This is your Application/Client ID
- client_secret - This is the Password/Client Secret
- scope - This should match the same set of scopes you initial requested
- redirect_uri - This is the redirect URI defined in your application registration

Also keep in mind that the POST should encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` rather than `application/json`.

I wrote an [primer on the v2 Endpoint](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/) that you might find useful here as well.